# Move Decking programs between characters in Shadowrun Returns?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

My character is the usual Street Samurai and I decided to not invest any Karma in Decking. But there's a point in the Seattle story where you need a decker.

Unfortunately I'm not being able to upgrade that guy's decking programs. Whenever I buy a program from a vendor, it gets added to my character's stash (viewable in the stash when talking to a decking vendor for example) and I can't upgrade the "hired" (not really) decker's programs.

Is there any way to transfer programs between characters or to upgrade a secondary character's programs?

I figure I'll be able to beat the game without this upgrade, but this feels broken. I don't recall if the original RPG book allowed such transfers, but I wouldn't buy it that SR's Deckers have unbreakable DRM on their programs bought from vendors ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deckers you get during the game, whether they're hired or story-given, always come with their own programs and, nine times out of ten, their entire deck is already filled with the programs they can and will use.  Same goes for ESPs.  The programs and ESPs that you buy as a character can only be used by you.  So, if you're not a decker, I wouldn't worry too much about the decking vendor.  You're hiring another guy to do the job.  He's got his own tools and knows he can get it done.  That's usually the end of it there.

I don't know about Shamans and summoning fetishes, though.  I have always hired my Shamans with them having at least two summoning fetishes, so I haven't needed to buy more.  What I've been finding is that the only items you can 'share' with your runners are consumable items.